# How are manhwa and manhua received in Japan?

Tags: culture

How popular are Korean *manhwa* and Chinese *manhua* in Japan?

Is there a market for them as localized manga?

Comment: Are you looking for sales volumes of Korean and Chinese comics publications in Japan?

Comment: @chirale While stats will be good, a reliable opinion will also be fine. Thank you.

Comment: This question is about manhwa and Japanese culture, but not about Japanese manga, so my interpretation of http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-should-manga-be-defined is that this is off-topic, though I do think it's potentially an interesting question. I've voted to close as such, but it may be worth continuing the discussion in meta as to this sort of question.

Comment: Based on our [expanded scope](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/415/24), this question now seems to be on-topic. Voted to reopen as such.